# Regular expression to match exact string with with non-numeric characters and variable number

Tags: java, regex, katalon-studio

I have been struggling with this and would appreciate any help.

I have a line of code that always looks like this:

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

`Thread.sleep()` is always a fixed sequence of characters, but the integer number inside is variable. How would I write a regular expression to catch this?

Comment: You want to get the '1000' part from `Thread.sleep(1000)`? The integer number inside is constant not variable. 1000 is not changing. What is your goal anyways? Seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: We have many lines of code like Thread.sleep(1000) or Thread.sleep(100) or Thread.sleep(2500).
We have written a special function to replace this.
I wish to do a RegExp search through the code for these lines and replace them with the new function.

Comment: @user15793316 Even better would be `Thread\.sleep\s*(\d+\)`. Inside a Java string, that would be `"Thread\\.sleep\\s*\\(\\d+\\)"`. Sometimes there can be whitespace before the `()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/JYa1jH/1), `Thread\s*\.\s*sleep\s*\(\s*\d+\s*\)`.

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `Thread`: Literal, `Thread`
- `\s*\.\s*`: `.` preceded by and followed by 0+ whitespace characters
- `sleep\s*`: Literal, `sleep` followed by 0+ whitespace characters
- `\(\s*`: The character, `(` followed by 0+ whitespace characters
- `\d+\s*`: One or more digits followed by 0+ whitespace characters
- `\)`: The character, `)`

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "Some Thread.sleep(1000) text";
        x = x.replaceAll("Thread\\s*\\.\\s*sleep\\s*\\(\\s*\\d+\\s*\\)", "");
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Some  text
```

Comment: Since you are using `\\s*` you can omit `\\R?` to have same effect.

Comment: I would consider trimming the double-space between the words, but it’s a detail. Nice, detailed answer.